# PHP - __call() confusion

Tags: php

I have some confusion with `__call()` and everything I search about it tells me it should work

```
<?php

class A {

    abstract public function C();

    private function B(){
        echo "B";
    }

    public function __call($method,$arguments){
        if(method_exists("C", $method)) {
            $this->B();
            return call_user_func_array(array("C",$method),$arguments);
        }
    }
}

class B extends A{

    public function C(){
        echo "C";
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->C();

//the result I get: 
// C
//the result I want;
// BC
?>
```

So, what I want as result is that I call function `C` but `B` get's echo'd out first. It worked at some point even, I am just really confused at what is going on. The php manual isn't that clear about it either, at least not what I am trying to do.

> **note**: The most confusing is, the above __call method is not reponsive anymore, if I do a test message in there, doesn't print it.

As said, I've got it to work at some magical moment. Can someone point me to what I am doing wrong, or is it possible? ( I have changed some stuff over time, so that might have changed the scenario.

Comment: Please show the code where you actually call these functions

Comment: @Machavity I have added what you asked for, this is the scenario I have.

Comment: `__call() is triggered when invoking inaccessible methods in an object context.` There's nothing inaccessible about your `C()` method

Comment: @MarkBaker I see that now, is it possible to achieve what I want in any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confusing what `__call` does. It's for inaccessible methods. So let's take `A`

```
class A {

    abstract public function C();

    private function B(){
        echo "B";
    }

    public function __call($method,$arguments){
        if(method_exists("C", $method)) {
            $this->B();
            return call_user_func_array(array("C",$method),$arguments);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, your `B()` is `private` but `C()` in your child is not

```
class B extends A{

    public function C(){
        echo "C";
    }
}
```

The problem is your code never touches `B()` the **method**. You're calling `B()` **the class**

```
$b = new B();
$b->C();
```

To get `__call` to work you need to do

```
$b = new B();
$b->B(); // invokes __call()
```

Comment: Ok ok, I can work with this! Thank you, as the titel already suggested I was a bit confused on this method.

Answer (score 0):

__call() is only invoked when the function isn't specified/accessible --

See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.methods

You cannot do what you are attempting to do.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Is it not possible at all to achieve what I want? I mean is there not another way?